# Stripe: Handle SEPA payment disputes through webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks, sepa

Im trying to implement in my rails app a way to handle disputes of *SEPA payments* through **Stripe**.

My original plan was to handle ***'charge.dispute.created'*** stripe event through the webhook but it seems like Stripe **doesnt send a webhook** for this event.

Is there any alternative way to handle disputes through webhook?

Comment: Stripe should definitely be sending `charge.dispute.created` events with SEPA disputes - how did you test this out to make sure you were seeing those events?

Comment: To extend on the previous comment: Have a look at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events (in test mode) or https://dashboard.stripe.com/events (live mode) to check if the event has been fired.

Comment: The events are fired in the Customer's "Events & Logs" since they are listed there.
But inside the "charge.dispute.created" event there is no webhook to my endpoint. In other events there is a webhook call.

Comment: So the event exists, but it just hasn't been sent to your webhook endpoint?

Comment: exactly , yes .

Answer (score 0):

For future reference.
You need to enable which webhooks will be fired along with the events per webhook endpoint.

***Developers > Webhooks > Click on the Webhook Endpoint > 3 dots menu on the upper right side -> Update details...***

And from the modal popup we select the event we want to send the webhook.